# If I scale this part, I can see some empty space there

Tags: mirror, scale

[image]

If I scale it more, this empty space is more bigger. this other mirror part 
'-'..help me.. how can I make no space there

Comment: Check "clipping" and "merging" in your mirror modifier settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it you appear to be using a mirror modifier. To fix this tearing caused by scaling; enable "clipping" in the mirror modifier window.

Use the GIF below for an example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3749X.jpg